# R batch txt file processing

Tags: r, file, dataframe, batch-processing

I am new to R and I want to batch process all files in a working directory.
I have lots of .txt files and want to read them in, calculate a frequency of one Column, calculate percentage and a so called "H-Score", calculate the sum of the H-Score and store it in a vector. Then the next .txt file should be processed and so on.

After all files are processed, I want to write the vector in another .txt file as a result. The final .txt file should also contain the name of the input file and the calculated sum of H-Score. This is what I have so far, but as you can see, I am a absolute Newbie to programming and R...

```
setwd("~/Desktop/Automated Analysis/TXT/") # Set working directory

 # List all txt files including sub-folders
list_of_files <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE,
                           pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE)

library(data.table)

# Read all the files and create a FileName column to store filenames
DT <- rbindlist( sapply(list_of_files, fread, simplify = FALSE),
                        use.names = TRUE, idcol = "FileName" )

br = c(0,1,3,9,15,500) # Set breaks
bins = c(0,1,2,3,4) # Set bins

for (k in 1:length(list_of_files)) { # process all the files in the working directory
  HScore_list = c() # create a vector for storing the results
  for(i in 1:5) { my_vector = c(HScore_list,i) }
  freq = hist(Count, breaks=br, plot=FALSE) 
  df = data.frame(bins, frequency=freq$counts,
          df$percent=df$frequency / sum(df$frequency) * 100,
          df$HScore=df$percent * df$bins)
  HScore = sum(df$HScore)
}
write(HScore_list, "HScore_list.txt", sep="\n")
```

Do you know what I want and can help me?

EDIT: My Problem is, that the Code is producing no output.

Comment: What's the exact problem you're running into? Post is too broad and there's no question in it.

Comment: You seem to be doing ok. What is the problem? If your problem is storing your H-Scores along with the filename they came from, suggest a dataframe/datatable or named list.

Comment: @PoGibas my problem is that the code is producing no output and I don't know where to start to fix it.

Comment: If your code is producing no output, sprinkle some print statements throughout, then tell us at which lines it's going wrong. Try single-stepping it with your debugger (RStudio, Jupyter or whatever). You have to do that, not us.

Comment: If output is empty, then start debugging each line: are there any `txt` files in the directory; is `DT` created; do column names match. In loop you can use `print` (eg, `print(dim(df))`)

Comment: OK, thank you. I will start debugging with RStudio as recommended. I will come back to you.. :)

Comment: In `freq = hist(Count ...`, Count is never defined. What is supposed to define it?

Comment: Then when you find the issue, cut your code down to the minimum needed to reproduce it. We don't need the file-reading or directory stuff. You could create a few random dataframes/datatables.